# React Redux Typescript APP Store Updated But Component Not Re - render

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux

On click of add button the data is getting added to the cart but the page doesn't get refreshed automatically once it is added. If I add hook React.useState() and update the state on click of button, after the dispatch then page is getting re-render.

As per my understanding page re-renders whenever state is updated.

Git Hub Link : https://github.com/iam-aki/green-mini-market.git

Comment: Github rep doesn't have any code

Comment: add code please. not links, links can be dead.

Comment: @turchak I have updated the repo.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you mutate the redux store. 
In you code:

```
        case CartActionTypes.ADD: {
        let itemExists = state.cart.find(cart => cart.productId === action.product.productId);
        if (itemExists) {
            itemExists.count = itemExists.count + 1;
            return {
                ...state,
                ...state.cart
            };
        } else {
            let cart: ICart = { productId: action.productId, product: action.product, count: 1 };
            state.cart.push(cart);
            return {
                ...state,
                ...state.cart
            };
        }
    }
```

Switch to

```
        case CartActionTypes.ADD: {
        let itemExists = state.cart.find(cart => cart.productId === action.product.productId);
        if (itemExists) {
            itemExists.count = itemExists.count + 1;
            return {
                ...state,
                cart: [...state.cart, itemExists]
            };
        } else {
            let cart: ICart = { productId: action.productId, product: action.product, count: 1 };
            return {
                ...state,
                cart: [...state.cart, cart]
            };
        }
    }
```

Comment: Worked perfectly fine, and rather doing this

cart: [...state.cart, cart]

I updated it to cart: [...state.cart], as same item was getting added twice.

Thanks for quick help. I wasn't able to identify the issue for a quiet long time. I am a JAVA developer and have recently started working on react redux.

Comment: @AnkitAggarwal forgot to delete `state.cart.push(cart);` from code. Now i updated the my answer